# How can I stream the same music to multiple computers?

Tags: music, streaming, music-streaming

Is there a way to stream the same playlist on multiple computers at the same time? I want to be able to sync what's playing on multiple computers (for parties etc).

Comment: What service are you using? Knowing which helps us give you a better answer

Comment: I don't have one. That's what I'm looking for. I usually play music through iTunes.

Comment: Free would be best. Poor college student and all that.

Comment: If you're using Apple products then [EarShot.me](http://earshot.me/) might be of interest (when it is released)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should have a look at [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/):

> Send any audio from your PC to AirPort Express units, Apple TVs, iPhones and iPods Touch, and even other PCs and Macs, all in sync! Airfoil for Windows gives you your audio, all around the house.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I'll be having his problem any time soon. I live in a small place, and I have only one computer!